# Libgdx auto-scrolling camera

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, sprite

I'm developing a libgdx game. What I want to do is to create a screen where some squares "falls" from the top to the bottom. So:

1. I have to set a background image.
2. I have to generate some squares randomly.
3. I have to move the screen from the bottom to the top.

In order to get that I'm using a Sprite for the background, a lot of sprites for the squares. Then a camera to move the screen.

In the render method I have:

```
 @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        batch.begin();

        backgroundSprite.draw(batch);

        for(Square square : squareList) {
            //Gdx.app.log("[Match]", square.toString());
            square.updatePosition();
            square.setSize(20, 20);
            square.draw(batch);
        }
        batch.end();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(fixedCamera.view);

        fixedCamera.position.y +=1;
        System.out.println("Camera position: x:" +fixedCamera.position.x+" y:"+fixedCamera.position.y);
        fixedCamera.update();
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
```

This is the code on the constructor. It's all I have in the class

```
final static int WIDTH = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
final static int HEIGHT = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/flat-earth-ui.json"));
        fixedCamera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        dynBatch = new SpriteBatch();
        backgroundSprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(scenario.getTexturePath())));
        backgroundSprite.setPosition(0,0);
        backgroundSprite.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        fixedCamera.position.set(0,0, 0);
        fixedCamera.update();
```

The items are displayed correctly, but when the camera moves, all the sprites disappears...
How can I fix that? Is there any way to handle that more efficiently?

Comment: Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); use in create() or show() method

Comment: Are you using stage in your game. fixedCamera is different from stage camera ?

Comment: what is viewport of your fixedCamera ?

Comment: I just use one camera (called fixedCamera). And I have in the class constructor:

Comment: stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

Comment: there is any Actor on Stage ??

Comment: more codes are needed ??

Comment: At the moment I haven't added any actor on stage

Comment: If you are not using any actor on Stage -> you are not using scene2d in game so remove stage from your game.

Comment: Ok thanks! I removed it, but the problem still remains :(

Comment: what is the value of WIDTH and HEIGHT ?

Comment: According to my understanding you want to scroll background Sprite only ?

Comment: one more question what is the need of another SpriteBatch **dynBatch** ?

Comment: I have updated the first post with the values of WIDTH and HEIGHT. I want to have three "layers". The lowest is the background, that it is fixed. In the middle we have have a lot of squares that have to "fall" from the top to the bottom of the screen (A square extends Sprite Class). The last layer is given by the camera. The camera have to move up (to give the falling down effect..)

Comment: DynBatch is just a remained element that I forgot to remove

Comment: why are you moving camera instead of that you can generate Square at Top of screen with random horizontal position and change y position of all Square(Sprite)

Comment: I thought it was easier and efficient :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved by these steps :

1. Create Sprite having screen Size and keep it on bottom.
2. Generate Square at Top of screen with random horizontal position and change y position of all Square(Sprite)
3. No need to move your camera. keep it in the middle of the screen.